# Add a column referencing identity column

Tags: sql-server

In my table `table1` I added a column `taxonomy_id` referencing `taxonomy_id` column of `taxonomy` table which is a identity column. 
Now I need to insert as many `taxonomy` records as there are records in table `table1` and I need to update `table1.taxonomy_id` to reference `taxonomy.taxonomy_id` accordingly.

How do I do that in SQL server? I could run a cursor, insert the rows 1 by 1 and use the `scope_identity()` but is that the only solution?

An example data set and structure:

```
--drop table taxonomy
create table taxonomy(taxonomy_id int identity, data varchar(50))

--drop table table1
create table table1(table1_id int, taxonomy_id int)

insert into table1 (table1_id) values (999), (777), (555), (22), (54423)
```

Comment: see output  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this what I have done:

```
-- declare a temp table
declare @temptab table(taxonomy_id int);

-- insert new rows into taxonomy table
-- return the IDs so we know which ones are the new ones
insert into taxonomy(data)
output inserted.taxonomy_id into @temptab
select 'table1 taxonomy data' from table1

-- update table1 with the IDs from the temp table
update table1
set taxonomy_id = t2.taxonomy_id
from (
    -- using the row_number makes little sense but..
    -- I needed a way to pair @temptab and table1 rows
    select table1_id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by table1_id) from table1 
) t1(table1_id, rownum)
inner join (
    select taxonomy_id, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by taxonomy_id) from @temptab
) t2(taxonomy_id, rownum)
on t1.rownum = t2.rownum
where table1.table1_id = t1.table1_id
```

Now each `table1` record is connected to a record in `taxonomy` table.

Answer (score 0):

[output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

```
insert into table1 (col1, col2) values (2,3), ...  
output inserted.iden
```

I am not following the specifics of your insert but above is the mechanics for getting the iden

??

```
insert into taxonomy (col1, col2)  
select col1, col2 from table1 
output inserted.id, inserted.col1, inserted.col2
update table1
   set table1.taxonomy_id  = inserted.id
  from table1 
  join inserted 
        on inserted.col1 = table1.col1 
       and inserted.col2 = table1.col2
```

Comment: You are welcome.  I am afraid the question did not give me much to work with.